# Android database does not work properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android `sqlite` database in Farsi (Persian) language, and I use the data in that for fill the `ListView`, but my problem is that I use item name in `ListView` in my query. For example, I get a name of `ListView`'s text and use it in my query, but some of them does not show me correct answer from `DB`. I use the Farsi class for queries.

Here is my code:

```
List<String> getSubjects(String db_name, String name) {

    List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    MyDataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    myDbHelper = new MyDataBaseHelper(this, db_name);
    try {
        cursor = null;
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "select distinct type from mydata where group like '%"
                        +         farsi.ConvertBackToRealFarsi(name) + "%'", null);
        if (cursor != null) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    String uname = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("type"));
                    collection.add(DariGlyphUtils.reshapeText(uname));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;
    }
    db.close();
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: Code always "works", but sometimes it does not do what we want it to do.  What did you input?  What did you get back?  What were you expecting?  Just saying "something's not right" gives us very, very little to help you with.

Comment: my inputs are farsi text that are in my list view.these text are from database. i get back nothing for some inputs and for some other it backs correct thing. what i expect is that return string in each row of database

Comment: what is your database collation ?

Comment: if yu want to khnow what are the type of data in has 1 integer and 4 string